# AS3 Mouse Over Change Image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, mouseover

Currently I'm trying to change image loaded in a sprite with mouseover event and change it back with mouseout. But it's not working correctly, am i missing something?

```
public class Tab extends Sprite
{
    var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var TabSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var SkinImages:Array = [Skin.TAB_ACTIVE,Skin.TAB_DISABLED,Skin.TAB_HOVER,Skin.TAB_VIEW];

    public function Tab()
    {   
        for each (var Image:String in SkinImages){
            imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(Image));
        }

        TabSprite.buttonMode = true;
        addChild(TabSprite);

        TabSprite.addChild(imageLoader);
        TabSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onTabHover);
    }


    private function onTabHover(e:MouseEvent){
        trace("HOVER");
        TabSprite.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onTabHover);
        imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(Skin.TAB_HOVER));
        imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event):void{
            TabSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onTabOut);
        });

    }

    private function onTabOut(e:MouseEvent){
        trace("OUT");
        TabSprite.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onTabOut);
        imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(Skin.TAB_VIEW));
        imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event):void{
            TabSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onTabHover);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should really load both images up front and toggle the visibility of each one. Also you don't appear to be adding the loaded images to a sprite.

Comment: One note about toggling visibility (instead of switching children), if two objects have the same (display) parent, and different visibilities, the parent dimensions will be affected by invisible child. As long as two children do have the same size this is not a problem, but if they don't, this may lead to many "wtf" moments with positioning of parent sprite. That is why in my answer I used addChild and removeChild instead of toggling "visible" parameter. It doesn't create hidden dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't nest listeners that way. Just add two in the constructor:

```
TabSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onTabHover);
TabSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onTabOut);
```

Note changing MOUSE_OVER to ROLL_OVER it's better in most cases. You shouldn't also load images at every mouse event. Preload them, and then use. Also using anonymous functions in listeners is bad practice as you are not able to remove that listener:

```
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event):void{
        TabSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onTabOut);
    });
```

And in fact you are not removing it - this is bad.

```
    for each (var Image:String in SkinImages){
        imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(Image));
    }
```

I doubt it works, I think you cannot load many images at once by using one loader.

Try this:

```
public class Tab extends Sprite
{
var imageOverLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var imageOutLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var TabSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
var SkinImages:Array = Skin.TAB_ACTIVE,Skin.TAB_DISABLED,Skin.TAB_HOVER,Skin.TAB_VIEW];

public function Tab()
{   

    TabSprite.buttonMode = true;
    this.addChild(TabSprite); // you also need to add as a Child "Tab" object in the Main Class

    imageOutLoader.load(new URLRequest(Skin.TAB_VIEW));
    imageOverLoader.load(new URLRequest(Skin.TAB_HOVER));
    TabSprite.addChild(imageOutLoader);

    TabSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onTabHover);
    TabSprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onTabOut);
}


private function onTabHover(e:MouseEvent){
    TabSprite.removeChild(imageOutLoader);
    TabSprite.addChild(imageOverLoader);

    trace("HOVER");

}

private function onTabOut(e:MouseEvent){
    TabSprite.removeChild(imageOverLoader);
    TabSprite.addChild(imageOutLoader);

    trace("OUT");

}
}
```

Try this.

Comment: I disagree. You get lots fewer unexpected behaviors when you're only listening for out when you know you're over, and vice versa.

Comment: And I for one disagree with you again. whenever you update your code and change any listener, you only need to change the listeners in one place if you declare them in a grouped location in your code (e.g. a constructor). If you forget to update your code in even just one place, you get a lot of errors (= unexpected behaviour). Grouping your listeners is still the best and you shouldn't remove them constantly.

Comment: I think what Łukasz Zaroda is referring to is the fact that the listener method for one particular event listerner contains the creation of another event listener, rather than having a function name then creating it in there. It is bad practice as it is likely to affect garbage collection.

Comment: I would say that juggling with listeners can be good, but only if you are going to have really big amount of that listeners, so if you can cut them by half, at the cost of code transparency, it's great. But I think in most cases, especially for beginners, it makes code too unclean. You can eventually at the end of development optimize the code in that matter but in the development stage it will be just a pain... I admit, I should clarify that in the answer. Affecting garbage collecting is also interesting but I have no knowledge about that topic.